# Is HTML tag such as <head>, <HTML> mandatory?

Tags: html, tags

Thanks for your consideration about this problem.
I started to learn HTML and knew that there're many kinds of tags.
For example, such as (HTML), (head), (body), (a), (div), (table).

But I wonder if these codes can be used separately or should include (HTML), (head), (body) format always.

Comment: Your question has been answered here: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/107734
Anyways the answer is: no, not at this time. Because browsers correct a lot of errors. A webpage still works without the html head and body tags. But the html is not valid according to the HTML specification. You can run into several unexpected problems if you don't include them, but you don't have to include them every time you try out a small piece of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An HTML document has two* main parts:

head. The head element contains title and meta data of a web document.
body. The body element contains the information that you want to display on a web page.
* To make your web pages compatible with HTML 4, you need to add a document type declaration (DTD) before the HTML element. Many web authoring software add DTD and basic tags automatically when you create a new web page.

In a web page, the first tag (specifically, ) indicates the markup language that is being used for the document. The  tag contains information about the web page. Lastly, the content appears in the  tag. The following illustration provides a summary.
[image]

HTML, HEAD, BODY is requried - than all content you should write in BODY section

HERE you can read official documentation https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html